# How to write Wireshark data to HBase with Flume

Tags: hadoop, hbase, wireshark, flume

I am trying to put real time wireshark data into HBase with Flume using following agent configurations.

Source

```
A1.Source.k1.type= exec
A1.Source.k1.command = tail -f /usr/sbin/tshark
```

Sink

```
A1.Sinks.C1.Type =  hbase
A1.Sinks.C1.columnFamily =
A1.Sinks.C1.table =
```

And I use tshark in root

`Tshark -i eth0`

Data seems to be stored but it looks like this - `x0/x0/x0/`.

Any idea where I am wrong